# Getting an Integrity Constraint Violation, When the value is not null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form that I am inserting data from, and I want it to insert into my mysql database. It also sends out an email. For some reason, when I fill out the name, email, and state input boxes on the form and submit, it says that "name" cannot be null, but I just entered my name! My database table is like so:

[image: database structure]

I was thinking since maybe I am not inserting anything for the id it was throwing it off, but why would it say name is null and not id?

My code(ENTIRE PAGE):

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  //variables to be used from each form field's input.
  $name = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
  $email = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ) );
  $state = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "state", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );

  //Blank fields cannot be submitted.
  if($name == "" || $email == "" || $state == ""){
    $error_message = 'Please fill in the required fields (Name, Email, State)';
  }

  //Honeypot for spam bots. if not blank, bad form input.
  if(!isset($error_message) && $_POST['details'] !== ""){
    $error_message = 'Bad form input!';
  }

  //Adding PHPMailer
  require( 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' );

  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  if(!isset($error_message) && !$mail->validateAddress($email)){
    $error_message = 'Invalid Email Address';
  }

  if(!isset($error_message)){
    //Creating the email body to be sent
    $email_body = "";
    $email_body .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    $email_body .= "State: " . $state . "\n";

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = "mail.me.net";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = "me@me.net";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    //Sending the actual email
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('me@me.net', 'Me');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Calculation form results from ' . $email;
    $mail->Body = $email_body;

    if($mail->send()) {
      //show thank you message
      header('location:index.php?status=thanks');
      exit;
    }
    $error_message = 'Message could not be sent. ';
    $error_message .= 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 6]><html class="preIE7 preIE8 preIE9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="preIE8 preIE9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="preIE9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="author" content="name">
    <meta name="description" content="description here">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords,here">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'thanks') {
        echo '<p>Thanks! Your data has been sent!</p>';
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "calculations";

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // prepare sql and bind parameters
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO people (name, email, state) VALUES (:name, :email, :state)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->bindParam(':state', $state);
            echo $name.' : '.$email.' : '.$state;
            $stmt->execute();
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        $conn = null;

      } else if(isset($error_message)) {
        echo "Error: " . $error_message;
      } else {
        echo "<p>Please fill out the following information below to calculate your results:</p>";
      }
    ?>
    <h2>Calculator</h2>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="name"> Name </label></th>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php if( isset($name) ){ echo $name; } ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="email"> Email </label></th>
                <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php if( isset($email) ){ echo $email; } ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label for="state"> State </label></th>
                <td>
                  <select id="state" name="state">
                    <option value="AL"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "AL" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "AK" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "AZ" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "AR" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "CA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>California</option>
                    <option value="CO"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "CO" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "CT" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "DE" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Delaware</option>
                    <option value="DC"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "DC" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>District Of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "FL" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "GA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "HI" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "ID" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "IL" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "IN" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "IA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "KS" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "KY" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "LA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "ME" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "MD" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "MA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "MI" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "MN" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "MS" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "MO" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "MT" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "NE" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "NV" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "NH" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "NJ" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "NM" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "NY" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>New York</option>
                    <option value="NC"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "NC" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "ND" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "OH" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "OK" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "OR" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "PA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "RI" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "SC" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "SD" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "TN" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "TX" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "UT" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "VT" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "VA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "WA" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "WV" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "WI" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY"<?php if( isset($state) && $state == "WY" ){ echo " selected"; } ?>>Wyoming</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;">
                <th><label for="details"></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" id="details" name="details" />
                  <p>Please leave this field blank.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So `echo $name.' : '.$email.' : '.$state;` outputs precisely what you expect right before calling `$stmt->execute();`?

Comment: Hmmm actually no! It is not displaying any of my variables! Why is it not getting the values I wonder? I may just say screw PDO and use MYSQLi... I'm new to PDO and the whole binding thing looks odd to me. My variables are created at the top of the program, so I don't think they could be out of scope to use..

Comment: I had a funny feeling you would tell me that :-). You've only shown snippets of code so I have no idea what is going on in between **Point A**: `$name = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );` and **Point B**: `$stmt->execute();`. How does your code transition from point A to point B?

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated and posted all the code.

Comment: Could it be because I use the exit command after sending the email? Maybe I need to do the insert before I use the exit command here:                                      `if($mail->send()) {
      //show thank you message
      header('location:index.php?status=thanks');
      exit;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work and insert. I had to move the code up to before the exit; command:

```
if($mail->send()) {
  //show thank you message
  header('location:index.php?status=thanks');
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "calculations";

  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      // prepare sql and bind parameters
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO people (name, email, state) VALUES (:name, :email, :state)");
      $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
      $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
      $stmt->bindParam(':state', $state);
      echo $name.' : '.$email.' : '.$state;
      $stmt->execute();
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
  $conn = null;
  exit;
}
```

The only thing about this is, if there is an insert error in the future, the error message is going to display in a different location than I wanted. I wanted it to display above the form so it is not just some white page with an error. I will figure this out, however. I forgot I had done the exit command earlier in my code.

Comment: is this your MySQL Error 1382 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_RESERVED_SYNTAX)
Message: The '%s' syntax is reserved for purposes internal to the MySQL server ??

Comment: No the error was just saying that my "name" value could not be null. I forgot the exact error.. But, I think when I had used the exit; command, it killed the script and I lost my variable values. That is why I couldn't use them to insert later on in the script. They were all null I guess. At least I THINK that is what happened... LOL

Comment: Where in the code you posted you use `exit()`? This does the trick yes. @JakeFromStateFarm

Answer (score 1):

Just a little suggestion that can save you some time. You should use this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO people (name, email, state) 
VALUES (:name, :email, :state)");
$stmt->execute(array(":name"=>$name,":email"=>$email,":state"=>$state);
```

Comment: You mean I can do this without using the bindparam thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you get `Integrity Constraint Violation` error regarding your query, try to re-write your query like this

```
INSERT INTO people (`name`, `email`, `state`) VALUES (:name, :email, :state);
```